# Is there any library to simulate sensors in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am making some application in android, and I want to use sensors. But when I use Sensor class, it says that I don't have any of them. My android version is 6.0 and API level 23 but it says I don't have ROTATION_VECTOR sensor for example. So I am wondering is there any library for that like Ketai library? But I need something that I can use in android studio. Does anyone know anything that can help me?

P.S. I am using real android device, not an emulator.

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: Physical device.